# Regex - match a "keyword string" inside a domain name or as word in <tr></tr>

Tags: regex, string, keyword

I'm having a problem finding table rows by "keywords".

Atm, I have 2 columns - domains and html title tag

What I need is to filter out the  matches that contain my keyword either in domains or title columns.

E.g. In the following examples, I want to output rows 1 and row 3 because keyword "fantasy" is in the domain name of row 1 and in the title tag of row 3.

```html
  <tr>
    <td align="left">greatfantasyparoxysm.com</td>
    <td align="left">Hardwood Paroxysm - Unbiased opinions from extremely biased people.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">medicinehelp.co</td>
    <td align="left">Medicine Help News</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">edsfootball.com</td>
    <td align="left">Best Fantasy Football Rankings and Cheat Sheets, NFL Mock Draft,   NFL Blog - EDSFootball.com</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Not sure that this will work for all cases, but you could test it (i've tried with some other keywords, and it worked): https://regex101.com/r/1mZ3x9/1 I am also sure that some regex guru will post better solution soon, but anyway, everyone will say that you shouldn't use regex in this case. :)

Comment: Given the current context (no programming language, no efforts, need to "filter"), the only advice is: open the HTML in Excel, and filter the columns with AutoFilter. If you need a more targeted hint/answer, provide all details related to your problem. For now, there is no problem, only a *task*.

Comment: Filter in excel only allows 2 filters simultaneously, I need to run 50 :)